# How to add delay between opening websocket connection and sending requests (not between requests) in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using a websocket plug-in to load test websockets. I want that there should be a few seconds delay between opening connection and sending infinite messages. I tried moving 2s delay around but i couldnt get it to work.

This is my config:
Number of threads: 1
Ramp up period: 0
Loop Count: 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a delay only before sending the first message - use [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler between these 2 Samplers.

[image]

If you want to create a delay before each request in the loop either move Flow Control Action sampler inside the Loop Controller or alternatively add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the "Single Write Sampler":

[image]

More information: [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)